# Qual plugin uso para poder comitar no GitHub usando PyCharm?

Tags: python, git

Sou iniciante em Python e gostaria de saber qual plugin é necessário para comitar no GitHub usando o PyCharm.

Comment: Não entendi mutio bem sua pergunta, mas não seria o git?

Comment: Eu, em Java, uso o Eclipse para comitar por meio do plugin eGit. Em Python, tenho a IDE PyCharm. Gostaria de saber qual plugin uso em Python para isso?

Comment: A pergunta devia ser "Qual plugin usar para fazer commit no GitHub usando PyCharm"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa de plugin, o PyCharm oferece suporte integrado ao Git. Dê uma olhada na documentação em [Registrando Credenciais do GitHub](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/registering-github-account-in-pycharm.html) e [Como Fazer Commit Num Repositório Git](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/committing-changes-to-a-local-git-repository.html).

Answer (score 0):

É só você fazer o download do git, ter uma conta no Github, e ir nas configurações do git no pycharm e adcionar o caminho até o git.exe pronto!